# Where are sales_flat_*_grid tables filled?

Tags: shipping

Hi i'm making a copy of the Shipping-Model for my own purposes. 
But i cannot find the point where the

```
sales_flat_shipment_grid
```

is filled. Can anybody show me?
I'm on magento 1.9CE

Comment: This is used for shipments. Not quite sure what your question means, esp in context of making copy of shipping model, more detail is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract` there is this method.

```
public function afterCommitCallback()
{
    if (!$this->getForceUpdateGridRecords()) {
        $this->_getResource()->updateGridRecords($this->getId());
    }
    return parent::afterCommitCallback();
}
```

This is called when a model is saved (including shipment).
This method calls `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract::updateGridRecords`.
That's the one that insert values in grid tables.